# Count the sum of each column in a file

Tags: command-line, scripts

In a file with different number of columns delimited by space ' ', How to count the sum of the columns. An example would show the need:

```
File A:

1 2 
2 3
4 5 6 
1 1 1 5
```

Then the output would be:

- for column 1 (1+2+4+1)=8
- for column 2 is 11
- for column 3 is 7
- for column 4 is 5

Answer (score 12):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum[i]+=$i;}; END{for (i in sum) print "for column "i" is " sum[i];}' FileA
for column 1 is 8
for column 2 is 11
for column 3 is 7
for column 4 is 5
```

Comment: Good use of arrays though I think it can get simplified to just counting sum and printing it right away

Comment: Indeed this is the best answer here.

Answer (score 6):

**Use `numsum` for that task** and separate between data processing and output the results.

Install `num-utils`, we need `numsum`

```
sudo apt-get install num-utils
```

And start with

```
numsum -c <your_file_name>
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat "File A"
1 2 
2 3
4 5 6 
1 1 1 5

$ numsum -c "File A"
8 11 7 5
```

or with your desired format:

```
$ numsum -c "File A" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print "for column "i" is "$i}}'
for column 1 is 8
for column 2 is 11
for column 3 is 7
for column 4 is 5
```

---

from `man numsum`

```
-c      Print out the sum of each column.
```

examples from `man numsum`

```
EXAMPLES

   Add up the 1st, 2nd and 5th columns only.

       $ numsum -c -x 1,2,5 columns
       15 40 115

   Add up the rows of numbers of a file.

        $ numsum -r columns
        55
        60
        65
        70
        75
```

Comment: LOVED `numsum -c` my new favorite!

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/sh

while read a b c d; do
    col1=$((col1 + a))
    col2=$((col2 + b))
    col3=$((col3 + c))
    col4=$((col4 + d))
done < File_A

echo $col1 $col2 $col3 $col4
```

Comment: You can probably say `(( col1 += a ))` , etc. Also, `echo "..."` is safer, as well as `while IFS= read -r ...`

Comment: @fedorqui `echo` is safe to be used that way to echo numbers, `$IFS` defaults at whitespace and those are expected to be numbers, so there's no need to deal with backslashes. The only downside of this answer is the need of knowing the number of the columns prior the execution.

Comment: @kos you can never know how an input file can be. And despite the OP mentions just numbers, it is always good practice to prepare for the worse. See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a magnific explanation.

Comment: @fedorqui Per your own statement I tought this was out of discussion; If you want to make points assuming that the input file could contain something other than numbers, you're missing the blatant part: checking if what is read is a number. Adding strings and using `echo "[...]"` to correctly print what you don't want to output makes no sense.

Comment: @kos You can of course say `echo $var` and `while read a b c`, it works here. However, you will get used to writing it in a weak way and one day you'll get strange errors while processing a more complex file. Then you'll notice quoting variables and using `while IFS= read -r ...` was safer and will say "oh yeah fedorqui was right, I hope I could have him around to hug him to show gratitude!".

Comment: Good and simple bash while loop. The only disadvantage is that you need to know number of columns in advance

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the comments to your own answer, you only want the sum of one column at a time.  If so, here is a non-awk way to do it:

```
cut -d' ' -f3 FileA | grep . | paste -s -d+ | bc
```

where you would replace the `3` with the column number you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner Perl script approach. This relies on the use of `-a` flag which allows auto-splitting currently read line with `-n` flag into array `@F`. All we have to do is iterate over those items, and add them to their respective index in `$sum` array, thus effectively each array item is sum for each respective column. Finally, we print the result within  `END` code block.

```
$ perl -lane '$j=0;foreach $i (@F){$sum[$j]+=$i; $j+=1;}; END{print join("\n",@sum)} ' input.txt                                                     
8
11
7
5
```

Alternatively, here's a full Perl script approach. It relies on splitting each line into array, and iterating over each item in that array adding each number to their respective possition in `@sums` array. The script prints out each line, then produces report for each column. Printing of each line can be removed by adding `#` before `printf("%s",$line);`

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh,"<",$ARGV[0]); 
my $i = 0;
my @sums;

while(my $line = <$fh>) { 
    printf("%s",$line);
    my @nums = split(" ",$line);
    my $j = 0;
    foreach my $num (@nums){
        $sums[$j] += $num;
        $j += 1;
    }

}

my $k = 0;
foreach my $sum (@sums){
    printf("- column %d sum: %d\n",$k,$sum);
    $k+=1;
}

close($fh);
```

The usage is simple `chmod +x ./sum_columns.pl && ./sum_columns.pl input.txt`. For example:

```
$ ./sum_columns_2.pl input.txt                                                                                                                       
1 2 
2 3
4 5 6 
1 1 1 5
- column 0 sum: 8
- column 1 sum: 11
- column 2 sum: 7
- column 3 sum: 5
```

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution:

```
awk '{sum += $i} END {print sum}' file
```

Replace i with column number for  example column1:

```
awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}' file
```

output is:

```
8
```

Comment: This only gets you one column. You aren't meeting your own specification.

Comment: I didn't state that i want all results in same command. plus this answer just need a loop and it be perfect

Comment: So why downvoting?